# I deployed a react app to AWS ECS and bought a custom domain, but I can not access it with "www" before the domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, web, https, amazon-ecs

so I can do "domain.com"

but I cannot do "www.domain.com"

additionally, when I add "https" to the beginning I get a "connection not private" message, however I have a public cert from amazon.

any ideas what's up with either problem?

Comment: Have you installed ssl cert on your load balancer?

Comment: https problem is solved now! not sure what was happening still but cloud front eventually deployed and it worked!

Comment: If you use Route53, how did you setup your records?

Comment: so in fact it didnt work when some friends were testing it on their browser.  I set up the route53 records by buying a domain from there and then going to the cert manager, creating a cert and then create a record to route53. I also added another hosted zone with 'www' explicitly in the domain and one with *.domain.com and forwarded them to the proper alias. still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `www` part is a subdomain of `domain.com`. You will need to handle routing when users visit this subdomain. You can either serve the same files as on the root domain, or you can redirect to `domain.com`.

To access your site via `https` you need to configure SSL.

You can use CloudFront and Route53 to solve these issues.

Here is a [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html) on handling routing for subdomains in Route53.

Comment: https now works , did end up using cloud front and route53.  still not able to get www. to reroute.  where am I looking for this exactly? hosted zones? the http listeners? cloud front?

Comment: so https actually does not work.  I am using cloud front and route53 tho

Comment: @RashanArshad In Cloudfront, did you set Viewer Protocol Policy to HTTPS redirect or HTTPS only? For routing to subdomains, AWS has a guide on this which you can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html)

Comment: I have it set to HTTPS redirect. ill check out the link rn , thank you.  interestingly the cloud front domain (not the custom one) gives a 502 error CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin

Comment: I can't seem to tell if it works or not.  Dont have too many devices to try from, if anyone can take a look and lmk if you get to the site and if there is/isnt a private connection error.  take a look if you can pls:  www.rashanarshad.com

Comment: @RashanArshad I just checked it out and everything seems to be working fine. `www` serves the same content as the root domain, all https requests are secure, attempting an http request redirects to https on both domains. Using godaddy's [ssl checker](https://www.godaddy.com/ssl-checker) says secure as well. SSL labs gives the site a B rating whiich is very strong - [report here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=rashanarshad.com&s=54.82.247.226)

Comment: awesome , thank you my man, appreciate the thorough checking!